# How salesforce supports inquiry management?

Tags: integration, appexchange

I want to set up an inquiry managment system for a company 
How salesforce supports inquiry management? should I integrate a third party app for that? or includes in salesforce itself

Comment: What are you calling an inquiry? A support case?

Comment: a case maybe!!!(I'm not sure).... the first requirement from customer sine before a bid decision by the operation department

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to achieve this . Below are some of the Options,

1) JIRA sevice desk to create Enquiry/requests & sync it back to CRM

2) Create a customer portal Object /model to handle inquries within salesforce

3) You can also make use of salesforce standard of called cases . Make you have a general email set to inquiry . Something like enquiry@123.com so that a case gets created within salesforce automatically